# Is this set $\left\lbrace\frac{1}{n}: n \in \mathbb{N}\right\rbrace$ a $G_\delta$ set?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Is the set $$\left\lbrace\frac{1}{n}: n \in \mathbb{N}\right\rbrace,$$ a $G_{\delta}$ set? I know that this set is $F_\sigma$, but not sure if it is $G_\delta$.

Edit: Thanks to everyone who commented very quickly. I guess my attempt would be to create the sets $A_n$ such that $A_n = (1-\frac{1}{n},1+\frac{1}{n}) \cup (\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}) \cup \cdots$. Then taking the intersection over all natural numbers leads to the desired set.

Is this correct?

Comment: Since you are using symbols $G_\delta$ and $F_\sigma$ you should bring context, or a brief explanation.

Comment: These are fairly standard terms from descriptive set theory. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%CE%B4_set What have you tried? Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, it is a $G_\delta$.  Now that you know this, try to explicitly construct the open sets and I don't really think you will have problems tbh  For example, what is the intersection of the intervals $(1-\frac{1}{n}, 1+ \frac{1}{n})$?

Comment: Perhaps prove more generally: the intersection of an open set and a closed set in $\mathbb R$ is a $G_\delta$.

Comment: Just updated the post, please feel free to give any feedback.

Comment: *Just updated the post, please feel free to give any feedback.* --- Each one of your sets $A_n$ contains $0,$ so the intersection contains $0.$ However, $0$ does not belong to the set that the intersection is supposed to be equal to. Try using intervals $(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{kn}, \; \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{kn})$ about the point $\frac{1}{n}$ to avoid having $0$ show up. Since $0$ is the only limit point of the set, there won't be any other "unintended guests" showing up when you take the intersection. You'll first take a union over $n$ (gives open sets), then an intersection over $k.$